# Why does appending to a list raise a NoneType error in Python?

Tags: python, list, append

Here is my code:

```
text="""col1 col2 col3
a 1 $
b 2 @
c 3 &
"""
mList = []
for line in text.splitlines():
    for item in line.split(" "):
        mList = mList.append(item)
```

This raises an error, `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'`. I've tried other ways of creating the list and doing this, but the best I get is the list turned to `None`. What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`list.append()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) is an in-place method, it does not return anything ( and hence by default it returns `None` , as all function *calls* must return some value, and if some function does not explicitly return anything, the call returns `None).

Hence, when you assign it back to `mList`, it becomes `None` and in the next iteration when you do - `mList.append()` , it errors out as `mList` is `None`.

You should try -

```
mList.append(item)
```

---

Or you can simply do what you are trying to do in a list comprehension -

```
mList = [item for line in text.splitlines() for item in line.split(" ")]
```

Answer (score 2):

[`list.append`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) does not return (= returns `None`), but just append the item into the list.

```
>>> lst = []
>>> return_value_of_append = lst.append('something')
>>> return_value_of_append is None
True
```

So the following line make the `mList` become `None`:

```
mList = mList.append(item)
```

Replacing the above line with the following solve the issue:

```
mList.append(item)
```